# oracle business intelligence aggregate tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee

Hi guys i have a problem when i run the aggregate script using presentation services.

aggregation script:

```
create aggregates 

"ag_Fact_budget"
 for "Budget"."Fact_budget"("MNT_DA_DEV","MNT_FACT","MNT_FACT_DEV","MNT_PAI_DEV","MONTANT_BUDGET")
 at levels ("Budget"."time"."year", "Budget"."type"."libelle")
 using connection pool "demo11g"."Pool de connexions"
 in "demo11g";
```

---

```
Error code : 
Error Codes: OPR4ONWY:U9IM8TAC:OI2DL65P
State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 43119] Query Failed: [nQSError: 37001] Could not connect to the Oracle BI Server instance. (HY000)
```

---

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8sBQ.png)

Comment: Check your connection code and settings

Comment: i tried everything . and it's work fine , the  connection etc..  but i don't understand the source of the error

Answer (score 0):

here is a image of  test connection using ODBC  [test connectivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQlL7.png)
[Error using nqcmd.exe command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahet1.png)